# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, validation, camera, android-camera, butterknife

I want put edittext from first activity to new secondactivity view text.

What to do when I have an erro like this displayed in android monitor :

```
com.example.xx.DrawerAddAd.seeAdd(DrawerAddAd.java:129)

com.example.xx.DrawerAddAd.access$100(DrawerAddAd.java:40)

com.example.xx.DrawerAddAd$2.onClick(DrawerAddAd.java:116)
```

also:
Render problem:
Couldn't resolve resource @id/visible
Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

DrawerAddAd class code:

```
package com.example.xx.drawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.example.xx.R;

import com.example.xxx.model.POJO.view.ProductDetails;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.BindView;

public class DrawerAddAd extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ArrayList<String> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private ImageButton camera_imageButton;
    private Spinner spinner_category;
    private Button button_seeAd_product;
    private Button button_add_product;

    @BindView(R.id.title_Ad_editText)
    EditText titleAd_editText;

    @BindView(R.id.text_Ad_editText)
    EditText textAd_editText;

    @BindView(R.id.price_editText)
    EditText price_editText;

    @BindView(R.id.checkBox_season)
    CheckBox checkBox_season;

    @BindView(R.id.checkBox_year)
    CheckBox checkBox_year;

    @BindView(R.id.checkBox_detail)
    CheckBox checkBox_detail;

    @BindView(R.id.checkBox_wholesale)
    CheckBox checkBox_whoLesale;

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private ImageView Image;
    private String userChosenTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_add_ad);

        final TextInputLayout title_ad_layout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_title_ad_layout);
        final TextInputLayout text_ad_layout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_text_ad_layout);
        final TextInputEditText title_Ad_editText = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.title_Ad_editText);
        final TextInputEditText text_Ad_editText = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.text_Ad_editText);
        setTextWatcher(title_Ad_editText, title_ad_layout);
        setTextWatcher(text_Ad_editText, text_ad_layout);

        spinner_category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
        button_seeAd_product = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_seeAd_product);
        button_add_product = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ad_product);

        camera_imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_imageButton);
        camera_imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

        button_seeAd_product.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean error = false;

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title_Ad_editText.getText().toString())) {
                    title_ad_layout.setError(getString(R.string.empty_field));
                    error = true;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text_Ad_editText.getText().toString())) {
                    text_ad_layout.setError(getString(R.string.empty_field));
                    error = true;
                }
                if (!error) {
                    seeAdd();
                }
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fragments, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_category.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void seeAdd() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("title",titleAd_editText.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("text", textAd_editText.getText().toString());

//        ImageView imageView =
//        String title = titleAd_editText.getText().toString();
//        String text = textAd_editText.getText().toString();
//        String price = price_editText.getText().toString();
//
//
//        intent.putExtra("titleAdd", title);
//        intent.putExtra("textAdd", text);
//        intent.putExtra("price", price);

        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.checkBox_season:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox_year:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox_detail:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox_wholesale:
                if (checked) {

                } else {

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setTextWatcher(final TextInputEditText editText, final TextInputLayout inputLayout) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (inputLayout.isErrorEnabled()) {
                    inputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
    }


    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Zrób zdjęcie", "Wybierz z katalogu", "Anuluj"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DrawerAddAd.this);
        builder.setTitle("Dodaj zdjęcie");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(DrawerAddAd.this);
                if (items[item].equals("Zrób zdjęcie")) {
                    userChosenTask = "Zrób zdjęcie";
                    if (result)
                        cameraIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Wybierz z katalogu")) {
                    userChosenTask = "Wybierz z katalogu";
                    if (result)
                        galleryIntent();
                } else if (items[item].equals("Anuluj")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    private void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Wybierz plik"), SELECT_FILE);
    }


    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Image.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

ProductDetails class code:

```
package com.example.xxx.model.POJO.view;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.xxx.R;

public class ProductDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView title, text, price, date;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_textView);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_textView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
//        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String title_textView = intent.getStringExtra("titleAdd");
        String text_textView = intent.getStringExtra("textAdd");

        title.setText(title_textView);
        text.setText(text_textView);


//        price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_textView);
//        date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_textView);

//        String titleAdd = bundle.getString("titleAdd");
//        String textAdd = bundle.getString("textAdd");
//        String price = bundle.getString("price");
//        title.setText(titleAdd);
//        text.setText(textAdd);
//        price.setText(price);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

I don't know what to do ...

Thanks, Slawek.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Post your xml file..

Comment: The solution is no binding :"  ButterKnife.bind(this);"
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_add_ad);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

Answer (score 0):

it means `title_Ad_editText` is null.
Check  your xml file and `title_Ad_editText` variable.

Answer (score 0):

couple things I could see, redo this:

```
private void seeAdd() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("title",titleAd_editText.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("text", textAd_editText.getText().toString());
```

to this:

```
private void seeAdd() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(DrawerAddAd.this, ProductDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("title",titleAd_editText.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("text", textAd_editText.getText().toString());
```

then in your intent, you need to call the extra exactly as set, change this:

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
//        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String title_textView = intent.getStringExtra("titleAdd");
    String text_textView = intent.getStringExtra("textAdd");
```

to this:

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
//        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String title_textView = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String text_textView = intent.getStringExtra("text");
```